# Create chat Application using c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2008, client-server, tcp

I  want to create a chat application in c# (windows form) using socket, TCP/IP communication
Client should sent text to server and server should respond and when server send message to client, client must receive that message. All the sending should be performed on button click event.
If anyone have worked on it kindly help me i am new to socket programming.

Comment: It seems you know the requirements, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

You cam refer the following link with server and client code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C

Answer (score 1):

Use TCP Server. Open Listener on the server using a port number, Let the listener accept socket in a new thread. Connect from the client using socket number and (IP Or Machine Name).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488668/Csharp-NET-TCP-Server